# Definition of the total variation of a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, bounded-variation

if the total variation of a a real function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ over $\textbf{P}=\{a=t_0<t_1<...<t_m=b\}$ is

$$
 V^{a}_{b}(f)=\sup_{\textbf{P}}V(f,\textbf{P})
$$
 where 
$$
V(f,\textbf{P})=\sum^{m}_{i=1}|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})|
$$
then what is the total variation of a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$? I didn't find a definition of this case.

Comment: Do you have an reason for suspecting this notion (variation on an unbounded set) is used? Off-hand, I think I've only seen variation defined for bounded sets, but I don't have any of my specialized books and other literature with me now to check.

Comment: yes, actually I've found in one of my books that the variation of such function is given by $V(f,\mathbb{R})=\sup_{a<b}V(f,\textbf{P})$ but what about the total variation ?

Comment: I would assume one would take the supremum of the variations over all compact intervals, which is equivalent (by monotonicity considerations) to what Eric Towers suggested, but I don't know of any nontrivial uses of the notion. I do have a suggestion, however. Try googling the phrase "generalized variation" (along with "function" or "Lebesgue" or whatever, to screen out non-math stuff). This will eliminate a lot of the standard elementary stuff that otherwise overwhelms the search results, and maybe in this more restricted advanced collection of hits you might stumble on something.

Comment: yes that's what I thought, but thanks a lot I'll google it.

Answer (score 1):

Do the same thing you do with integrals:  Take the (independent) limits as $a \rightarrow -\infty$ and $b \rightarrow \infty$.